# Font, letter E sans vertical bar

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Is there a font where the capital E has no vertical bar?  I got the idea from the font used in the movie Elysium, but I think it only appears in the credits.

Any help is appreciated.

Best,
Loque

Comment: You could try creating the glyph yourself and seeing if [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) recognizes it as anything

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you'll like [TELE MARINES FONT](http://www.dafont.com/tele-marines.font)

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you want to try is the [Varino Font](https://fontmeme.com/fonts/varino-font)
[image]